# Width of screen is not calculating correctly when using scrollbar-gutter stable

Tags: javascript, html, css

> Note: `scrollbar-gutter: stable;` is not supported in Safari. Futhermore, the issue is only happening in Chrome, but works as expected in Firebox.

When trying to position elements fixed to the viewport when using `scrollbar-gutter: stable`, I am noticing some weird behavior.

When there is a scrollbar, or a `stable` scrollbar gutter, the full screen width is supposed to account for the scrollbar/gutter and subtract its width. This way, position `right: 0;` does not end up behind the scrollbar, but rather where it starts.

However, as you can see in my snippet, the width is instead ignoring the gutter and giving the full width as if the gutter wasn't even there. This causes my red div to not be centered correctly and my yellow div to end up behind the scrollbar (even blocking some of the text).

When you click on the screen in my snippet, the width of the div is being logged to the screen. You can see that it initially shows the correct width where it takes the gutter into account. However, for no explainable reason what so ever, on the second click, the width has changed all of a sudden and you get the incorrect width. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

```js
const test = document.querySelector(".container");

document.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(test.clientWidth))
```

```css
html {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: skyblue;
}
.test1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: salmon;
}
.test2 {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 4.5rem;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test2">Some text example</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest this feels like a browser bug to me, I can't see any legitimate reason why the `clientWidth` should be changing here. With a brief look I've not been able to find any existing bug reports, this might be something worth raising.

Comment: @DBS Surely it got to be a bug. Where can I report this bug?

Comment: I am also very confident (90% at least) that this issue did not happen in earlier Chrome versions as I remember using scrollbar gutter for simular reasons without having this issue. If anyone who hasn`t updated chrome in a couple of months could check that would be amazing

Comment: Do you want to address the issue or just know the "why" here? 
 Note that if you click fast, the numbers change after some indeterminate number of clicks.  Probably because there are "scroll" and "scrollend" events being fired behind the scenes for some small period of time.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I welcome any discussion about the issue. Though I believe it probably is a bug and has no great solution other than for the chrome team to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a bug reported in Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251856 ("Issue 1251856: Elements with position: fixed should respect scrollbar-gutter: stable" from September 2021, still open as of January 2024).

Depending on the use case there may be ways to work around this. `width: 100vw;` seems to always be the same. So `position: fixed; left: 50vw;` does at least not jump. And `left: 100%; transform: translateX(-100%);` does attach an element on the left side of the stable gutter/the scrollbar. (But don't try to dynamically apply `overflow: hidden` to `html`, this triggers the bug again.

I haven't checked JavaScript yet, but one may be able to read positions from a (hidden) element to get the value one needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on ALL your requirements but given just the HTML you have you can use a grid and center the salmon block by putting it in the "center" of a grid with an automatic row 5 and put the yellow one in the first 2 of 4 grid rows specified.

Removed all the placement (fixed etc.) and just used the view to determine size.

I quickly added two elements and place them as a large '+' on the container.

I used a grid for the body and placed those. I also used a grid for the container and placed your salmon/yellow on the container grid also.

Thus with all that the salmon (and "+") stay in the center of the grid (using the automatic 5 there) and the yellow on the right top two grid rows of 4.

Resize to full screen and height to get the right scroll bar and you see the scroll appears "over" the padding on the yellow block without overlay of the text.

Perhaps this layout will work better with those modern CSS tactics.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

document.querySelector('.test1').addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.textContent = document.body.clientWidth + ' | ' + container.clientWidth;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.container {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4.5em 1fr 4.5em;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: skyblue;
}

.test1 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background: salmon;
}

.test2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 4.5em;
  background: yellow;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.hori {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 75vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.vert {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 75vh;
  border: 1px solid lime;
  width: 1px;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test1"></div>
  <div class="test2">Some text example</div>
</div>
<div class="hori">
</div>
<div class="vert">
</div>
```